# What to update in overridding template files for Magento SUPEE-6285

Tags: magento, patch

I am looking for hosted diffs regarding the SUPEE-6285 patch, or what specifically to update in the changed template files re: [this list](http://blog.philwinkle.com/supee-6285-broken-down/)

The template files updated by this patch are likely (in my case, actually) overridden by local template files. The patch updates /base/ templates fine, I am wondering what the necessary changes are that I need to make to eliminate the vulnerabilities in the local / overridding files.

Comment: The SH patch file itself is a diff.

Comment: @DouglasRadburn yes, yes it is. However the patch is different for the various versions I need to update (1.8.0.0 and 1.8.1.0), so I was hoping that someone had a hosted diff of the various base vs. patched versions that I could more easily analyse. meh... maybe I should post the gist.